# Are intermittent issues off-topic when they can be fixed just by waiting?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I just encountered [this close vote review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15944975) concerning a question about an intermittent issue which disappeared after a few hours, and seems to have been caused by an issue at Apple side.

As such, it would indeed be off-topic since it is “a problem that can no longer be reproduced”.

However, looking at the comments and answers, it seems this problem still occurred now and then to other people (last time in January), and even sometimes for other reasons.

I wouldn't say that it “was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers” because even the “*Sit on it for a couple hours and try it again*” answer would actually be helpful.

The number of upvotes also seem to indicate that it is helpful.

So, is this really off-topic?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326251/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-a-temporal-event-which-gets-a-lot-of-attention

Comment: Based on the answers, it looks like the issue can be caused by multiple factors, the most common of which is a recurring error on apple's end. This question may not be reproducible _all_ the time, but the next time someone comes along wondering why that's happening, it would be nice if that question was there to help them.

Comment: @TinyGiant Indeed I think the question should remain even if it was closed. But with the positive score it wouldn't be deleted automatically, right?

Comment: Why are you asking us?  The point of reviewing is that *you* decide.  If you are not sure then click Skip.  If you don't think it is valid then click Leave Open.

Comment: I would review it as leave open, because there is no reason for it to be closed. We close questions to prevent them from being answered. I see no benefit to preventing that question from receiving answers.

Comment: My take on the situation is that if this is a one off issue and will never again cause questions to be asked on SO then we can close it as not reproducible and be done with it.  If it keeps coming back up then at least having one question around that we can use as a dupe target for when the issue comes back seems like the thing to do.

Comment: @HansPassant The goal of asking is to have a guideline, it is not specific to this question. Also, the review should be as objective as possible. And even if I skipped it, I find it important to wonder how to handle those cases in the future.